# Set heap size for -jar command

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I want to set heap size under Linux OS in order to use it on java -jar command.
I have tried to add _JAVA_OPTIONS property under .bash_profile, but this property is ignored. I know I can run my jar with 
java $_JAVA_OPTIONS -jar 
command or create an alias like 
alias java='java -Xms256m -Xmx512m' 
I have found I can also export _JAVA_OPTIONS:
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m"
But this property is not kept between sessions.
Any idea how can I set permanent heap size for java -jar command?

Comment: Seems strange that you can `export` but not in the .bash_profile. Are you sure that you `export`ed in that file? Also depending on your os you might have to log back in to see changes.

Comment: I found my mistake, it was mistype in .bash_profile. 
It works properly now.